# Program throwing OperationCanceledException despite catching it

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, exception

I'm trying to use Tokens to cancel Task started by Task.Run. I took pattern from microsoft site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/hh160373(v=vs.110).aspx

This is my code:

```
public static class Sender
{

    public static async Task sendData(NetworkController nc) {
        await Task.Run(() => {
            IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(nc.serverIp, nc.dataPort);
            byte[] end = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("end");
            while (true) {
                if (Painting.pointsQueue.Count > 0 && !nc.paintingSenderToken.IsCancellationRequested) {

                    byte[] sendbuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Painting.color.ToString());
                    nc.socket.SendTo(sendbuf, endPoint);

                    do {
                        sendbuf = Painting.pointsQueue.Take();
                        nc.socket.SendTo(sendbuf, endPoint);
                    } while (sendbuf != end && !nc.paintingSenderToken.IsCancellationRequested);

                }
                else if (nc.paintingSenderToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
                    nc.paintingSenderToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }, nc.paintingSenderToken);
    }
}
```

And here I start this task:

```
    public void stopController() {
        try {
            paintingSenderTokenSource.Cancel();
            senderTask.Wait();
        } catch(AggregateException e) {
            string message = "";
            foreach (var ie in e.InnerExceptions)
                message += ie.GetType().Name + ": " + ie.Message + "\n";
            MessageBox.Show(message, "Przerwano wysylanie");
        }
        finally {
            paintingSenderTokenSource.Dispose();
            byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("disconnect");
            IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(serverIp, serverPort);
            socket.SendTo(message, endPoint);
            socket.Close();
            mw.setStatus("disconnected");
        }

    }

    public async void initialize() {
        Task t = Reciver.waitForRespond(this);
        sendMessage("connect");
        mw.setStatus("connecting");
        if (await Task.WhenAny(t, Task.Delay(5000)) == t) {
            mw.setStatus("connected");
            Painting.pointsQueue = new System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<byte[]>();
            senderTask = Sender.sendData(this);
        }
        else {
            mw.setStatus("failed");
        }
    }
}
```

In `initialize()` method I'm waiting for the response from the server and if I get it I start new thread in this `sendData()` method. It is in static class to make code cleaner. If I want to stop this thread I call `stopController()` method. In microsoft site we can read:

> The CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested method throws an OperationCanceledException exception that is handled in a catch block when the calling thread calls the Task.Wait method.

But my program breaks on`nc.paintingSenderToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` which is in 'sendData()' method and the error says that OperationCanceledException was not handled. I started program from microsoft site and it works perfectly. I think I'm doing everything like they did but unfortunately it doesnt't work like it should.

Comment: Quick question, do you have "Enable Just My Code" enabled?

Comment: Yes, I have it enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You may have "Enable Just My Code" enabled. 
To find the settings go to:

> Tools => Options => Debugging => General => Enable Just My Code

If this checkbox is checked could you un-check it and then run your application again.

Comment: Well it helped but not exacly. Program doesn't break now but it freezes on 'senderTask.Wait()'. In debuuger I can see that thread is still running.